# Oracle query cumulative amount

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table that ordered by Date Asc. I need the column Progressively Netv that sum Progressively the column Netv for eatch row.

```
ID      Type      Date        NetV   Debit  Credit   Vat  Progressively NetV
177485  Invoice   23/12/2015    900   1107       0  1.23   900
177485  transfer  14/1/2016       0      0    1107     0   900
177485  Invoice   24/3/2016     900   1107       0  1.23  1800
177485  transfer  27/5/2016       0      0    1107     0  1800
177485  Invoice   30/6/2016     900   1116       0  1.24  2700
177485  transfer  5/8/2016        0      0    1116     0  2700
177485  Invoice   28/9/2016     900   1116       0  1.24  3600
177485  transfer  4/11/2016       0      0    1116     0  3600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. What I understand is that you want to have something like:

```
  select id, type, date, NetV, Debit, Credit, Vat, 
         sum(NetV) over (partition by id order by date) as ProgressivelyNetV 
  from table1;
```